# How do I build and run a Java Swing application on a Chromebook?

Tags: java, swing, x11, google-chrome-os, chromebook

What steps are needed to build and test a Java Swing application on a chromebook using Crostini?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following steps allowed me to build and run a Java Swing app from a chromebook.

After enabling Linux on my chromebook, I ran the following commands in a terminal to install java, maven, and an X11 server.

```
sudo apt install x11-apps
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
sudo apt install maven
```